# AWS Beanstalk Laravel post deploy hooks no such file or directory

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy laravel app to aws beanstalk, OS is Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

I've setup following files:

```
.ebextensions/01-deploy-script-permission.config
```

It contains below code:

```
container_commands:
    01-storage-link:
        command: 'sudo chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/post-deploy.sh'
```

And

```
.platform\hooks\postdeploy/01-post-deploy.sh
```

It contains below code:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Upon deploying it fails with following entry in eb-engine.log file

> [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] -
> [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error:
> Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/post-deploy.sh failed with error
> fork/exec .platform/hooks/postdeploy/post-deploy.sh: no such file or
> directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is for users who are using **Windows** to deploy their files to elastic beanstalk.

I found this information after spending 6 precious hours. Probably not documented anywhere in official documentations

As per this link "https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=321653"

> psss: most important that the file is saved with LF line separator.
> CRLF makes "no file or directory found"

So I used Visual Studio Code to convert CRLF to LF for files in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy`

> At the bottom right of the screen in VS Code there is a little button
> that says “LF” or “CRLF”: Click that button and change it to your
> preference.

Comment: I run all my scripts through `dos2unix` as one of my first ebextensions steps, which takes care of this problem. Some of us develop on/deploy from Windows, and others use Macs.

Comment: Related, for maven users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162678/2751039

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but I think you are running the command before the files are even created hence getting the following error.

A while ago I faced the same kind of problem where I wrote migration commands in .ebextension and it used to give me an error because my env file wasn't even created yet hence no DB connection is made so I was getting the error. Hope this will give you a direction.
By the way, I resolved the problem by creating env then pushing these commands through the pipeline.

Comment: I had a different issue, it was related to line-ending: It is not document in AWS docs anywhere but found from community: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66047579/1550566